# Match two tables based on minimum dates efficiently

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have two tables one which contains quarterly data and one which contains daily data. I would like to join the two tables such that for each day in the daily data the quarterly data for that quarterly is selected and returned daily. I am working with Postgres 9.3.

The current query is as follows:

```
select 
  a.ID, 
  a.datadate, 
  b.*, 
  case when a.datadate = b.rdq then 1 else 0 end as VALID 
from proj_data a, proj_rat b
where a.id = b.id
and b.rdq = (select min(rdq) 
             from proj_rat c 
             where a.id = c.id and a.datadate >= c.rdq);
```

But it is excruciatingly slow and I need to do this for several thousand IDs. Can anyone suggest a more efficient solution?

Comment: I created indexes on rdq and ID and it went from a few minutes to a couple milliseconds.

My bad. I'm still curious if anyone has anyone has a more efficient query.

Answer (score 0):

This eliminates the need for a subquery in the `where` clause

```
select 
    ID, 
    a.datadate, 
    b.*, 
    (a.datadate = b.rdq)::integer as VALID 
from
    proj_data a
    inner join
    (
        select distinct on (id, rdq) *
        from project_rat
        order by id, rdq
    ) b using(id)
where a.datadate >= b.rdq;
```

Comment: Lots of useful syntax there. It is fast but it's returning  107205 rows for my test ID whereas I am expecting 3393. This is why I thought I needed the min(rdq) clause, else it matches to everything in the past as well.

Comment: @Michael Did you use the version `distinct on (id, rdq)` or the one which I quickly edited `distinct on (id)`?

Comment: @ Clodoaldo Neto distinct on (id, rdq)